# How can I use sql to select records of students who have grade value less than or equal to 6 in both mathematics and Engish Language

Tags: sql, math, select, subquery

I have 3 tables and their columns as follows.

```
Table: Studenttable (StudentID)
Table: Subjecttable (SubjectID) 
Table: SubjectName  (Gradetable,gradevalue).
```

I want to use sql to select **only records of students who have got gradevalue <= 6 in both Mathematics and English Language.**

But whenever i run the query, I have some students with  gradevalue <= 6 in either Mathematics or English Language as part of my record.

This is the look of the table relationshi.[Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cVV4.png)
This is the sample output which has some records with candidates with either Mathematics or English. (Which I want to exclude from the recordset) [OutputSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Ft2.png)
This is the sql I used

SELECT tblCandidates.CandidateID, tblCandidates.CandidateName, tblSubject.Subject, tblGrade.GradeValue
FROM tblSubject INNER JOIN (tblGrade INNER JOIN (tblCandidates INNER JOIN tblStudentGradeDetails ON (tblCandidates.CandidateID = tblStudentGradeDetails.CandidateIDFK) AND (tblCandidates.YearIDFK = tblStudentGradeDetails.YearIDFK) AND (tblCandidates.SchoolCodeIDFK = tblStudentGradeDetails.SchoolCodeIDFK)) ON tblGrade.GradeID = tblStudentGradeDetails.Grade) ON tblSubject.SubjectID = tblStudentGradeDetails.Subject
WHERE (((tblSubject.Subject) In ("Mathematics (Core)","English Language")) AND ((tblGrade.GradeValue)<=6));

Comment: Please tag appropriate database and post the query you are trying with. Also please add some sample data from different table with your expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks very much for attending to my problem. Please I have editted my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should really change tblStudentGradeDetails to have the SubjectId and GradeId from its' corresponding tables instead of the Subject(name) and Grade(name).

```
SELECT
    c.CandidateID
,   c.CandidateName
,   s.Subject
,   tblGrade.GradeValue 
FROM tblCandidates c
JOIN tblStudentGradeDetails sg 
    ON sg.SchoolCodeIDFK = c.SchoolCodeIDFK
JOIN tblSubject s 
    ON s.Subject = sg.Subject
JOIN tblGrade g
    ON g.Grade = sg.Grade
WHERE   s.Subject IN ('Mathematics (Core)', 'English Language')
    AND g.gradeValue >= 6
```